# Is there any way to make apps with fixed vertical orientation rotate?

Tags: ios, ipad, settings

A number of apps on my iPad (iPad Air 2, iOS 12.3) are designed so that they won't rotate--they are vertically oriented only with the camera at the top of the screen. Is it possible to get these apps to rotate so that the camera is at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iOS app can be programmed to support any one, more or all of the following orientation modes:

- Portrait
- Upside Down
- Landscape Left
- Landscape Right

If talking about the portrait mode(s), while the apps targeting iPhone are generally configured to only support *Portrait* mode (front camera at the top), the ones for iPad support both *Portrait* and *Upside Down* (front camera at the bottom) mode.

If the app is question is programmed to *only* support Portrait mode, there is no way for the user to also make it work in Upside Down mode.